# Build throwing error "Command ... llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"

Tags: c, xcode4, compiler-errors, llvm-gcc

Here's the log from the build. This is a brand new project in Xcode 4, so the only non-regular things in it are as follows:

1. A .c file
2. A .a library
3. A bunch of header files

I've been playing with the build settings and searching for answers for a couple of hours now to see if it would go away, but it didn't. Any help you have would be appreciated.!

The output (click for a larger image):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a duplicate symbol error - your program can't have two functions called `main()`.  Remove one of them, and you should be able to move forward.

Comment: Thanks! This is the first time I've been dealing with external libraries and other files than Objective-C so I'm kind of confused. But I went into the .c file and changed the main() function to something else. Thanks!